# npm can't uninstall hummus

Tags: npm, node-modules, hummus.js

I keep getting this error when I try npm install on Ubuntu 18.04.3

```
Creating an optimized production build...

<--- Last few GCs --->

[17781:0x44c8c50]    66207 ms: Scavenge 993.2 (998.1) -> 993.0 (998.6) MB, 8.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.258, current mu = 0.275) allocation failure
[17781:0x44c8c50]    66541 ms: Mark-sweep 993.6 (998.6) -> 987.0 (998.6) MB, 311.6 / 0.0 ms  (+ 408.1 ms in 74 steps since start of marking, biggest step 39.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 859 ms) (average mu = 0.338, current mu = 0.412) allocation

<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x13da519]
Security context: 0x14eb4ac40921 <JSObject>
    1: _parseMappings(aka SourceMapConsumer_parseMappings) [0x5db3f57c879] [/home/david/ammonite/node_modules/webpack-sources/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map-consumer.js:~468] [pc=0x39c0c766bcd2](this=0x025377be5539 <BasicSourceMapConsumer map = 0x2d995f50c241>,0x39d765cbd3f1 <Very long string[4863]>,0x3732a4e401c1 <null>)
    2: get [0xdd226766261] [/home...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xa0e670 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xa0ea9c node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xb83afe v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xb83e79 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xd32305  [node]
 6: 0xd32996 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [node]
 7: 0xd41209 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 8: 0xd42045 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 9: 0xd44b1c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
10: 0xd0a2cd  [node]
11: 0xd0b4e2 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRawFixedArray(int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [node]
12: 0xd0b9e8 v8::internal::Factory::NewPropertyArray(int) [node]
13: 0xee56f9 v8::internal::JSObject::MigrateToMap(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, int) [node]
14: 0xeffef2 v8::internal::LookupIterator::ApplyTransitionToDataProperty(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSReceiver>) [node]
15: 0xf314b1 v8::internal::Object::AddDataProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::Maybe<v8::internal::ShouldThrow>, v8::internal::StoreOrigin) [node]
16: 0xf320a7 v8::internal::Object::SetProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::StoreOrigin, v8::Maybe<v8::internal::ShouldThrow>) [node]
17: 0x106e72a v8::internal::Runtime::SetObjectProperty(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::StoreOrigin, v8::Maybe<v8::internal::ShouldThrow>) [node]
18: 0x106f8fa v8::internal::Runtime_SetKeyedProperty(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
19: 0x13da519  [node]
Aborted (core dumped)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! ammonite@0.1.0 build: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ammonite@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-08-10T19_07_33_865Z-debug.log
```

I tried doing

```
npm uninstall hummus --save
```

which also doesn't work.

I don't want hummus and can't understand why it keeps reinstalling itself.

Atm I can't build my project either and keep getting err 134 when I try npm run build.

Comment: I expect there's more output than the one line, *how* does it fail to (un)install?

Comment: I looked at the debug log but it was 8399 lines long! I did try npm install build-from-source but that hasn't worked either